# Relative feature importance w.r.t hyperparameters

Tags: feature-selection, feature-engineering

Could changing the hyperparameters of a model change ***relative*** feature importance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. The most obvious example is when using a Lasso regression : for an increasing $\alpha$ parameter you will have more and more coefficients set to zero. This resulting in a smaller set of features and thus a bigger share of feature importance for remaining features.

Comment: Right but could relative feature importance change? Like say "longitude" was ranked better than "latitude" for a given set of parameters. Could this be reversed (so "latitude" ranked better) for some other set of parameters?

Comment: Yes. Features having similar importance switch easily when changing parameters. (even when taking a different sample of data)